# Terminal : Is there any way to print the file names located in specific directory?

Tags: linux, terminal

What I want to do is,

```
└── super_crawler
    ├── config
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── celery.py
    │   ├── settings1
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── development1.py
    │   │   ├── partials
    │   │   │   ├── my_name1
    │   │   │   ├── is1
    │   │   │   ├── choi1
    │   ├── settings2
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── development2.py
    │   │   ├── partials
    │   │   │   ├── my_name2
    │   │   │   ├── is2
    │   │   │   ├── choi2
```

In current location, which is `super_crawler`, I want to print out `my_name1, is1, choi1, my_name2, is2, choi2`, **which are located under the directory named `partials`(This is the POINT!)**, in the terminal screen using only ONE LINE command.

I looked for some ways to do this but can not get any solution and post this question.

Need your help. Thanks

Comment: `ls config/settings1/partials ; ls config/settings2/partials`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two ls commands on one line separated by a semicolon:

```
ls -1 config/settings1/partials ; ls -1 config/settings2/partials
```

Or, use `find`. It outputs relative path from the current directory, so I used `cut` to remove it:

```
find config/*/partials -maxdepth 1 -type f | cut -d/ -f4
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I'm looking for! I have a one more question. What if I want to extract files starting with "__" in the resulting output? Really thankful   if you answer this, too :)

Comment: You can start a new question to ask a new question.